# scikit-learn documentation example: 'got an unexpected keyword argument'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, unsupervised-learning

When running [this example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#homogeneity-completeness-and-v-measure) from the scikit-learn documentation, I get the error `v_measure_score() got an unexpected keyword argument 'beta'`:

```
from sklearn import metrics
labels_true = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
labels_pred = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
metrics.v_measure_score(labels_true, labels_pred, beta=0.6)
```

It looks like a bug in sklearn.metrics... Any insights?

Comment: i am using '1.0.2' version of scikit-learn and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be using an old version of scikit-learn.
According to scikit-learn documentation the beta keyword was introduced in version 0.21

Comment: Yeah, I did not notice I was using an old conda env having a similar name to the new one. Thanks! :)